# PowerCenter Mapping with 1 Input writing to 2 identical outputs

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

I have a large file(~10GB) that I need to read and then publish to two identical tables on different servers.

Is there a way to replicate the output to publish to 2 servers instead of creating two mappings and reading through the file twice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes that is certainly possible through one Informatica mapping. Just connect the two target instances from the same source qualifier.

Comment: yeah I could have sworn that I tried that before and it didn't work.  But I actually did this yesterday and it worked like a charm.  Thanks.